# Does ramda.js create a deep clone of the original object when using R.set or R.merge?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Does anyone know if ramda.js creates a deep clone of the original object when using R.set(lens, newValue, object) or R.merge(object, newObject)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ramda will reuse object values and copy by reference when constructing new objects with functions like `R.merge` and `R.set` rather than cloning them unnecessarily. This is based on the assumption that the data types used will always be used in an immutable manner.

The examples below should illustrate where the values differ inside the objects when given to `merge` or `set`.

```
// merge example
const obj1 = { a1: { b1: { c1: {}, c2: {} }, b2: {} }, a2: {} }
const obj2 = R.merge(obj1, { a2: 3 })

// only `a2` is modified, so the other values are copied by reference
obj1.a2 === obj2.a2 // false
obj1.a1 === obj2.a1 // true
obj1.a1.b1 === obj2.a1.b1 // true
obj1.a1.b1.c1 === obj2.a1.b1.c1 // true

// lens example
const c1Lens = R.lensPath(['a1', 'b1', 'c1'])
const obj3 = R.set(c1Lens, {}, obj1)

// `a1.b1.c1` was modified, so each parent object needs to be recreated as new
obj1.a1 === obj3.a1 // false
obj1.a1.b1 === obj3.a1.b1 // false
obj1.a1.b1.c1 === obj3.a1.b1.c1 // false

// `a2`, `a1.b2`, `a1.b1.c2` were unaffected by the change so they retain the same references
obj1.a2 === obj3.a2 // true
obj1.a1.b2 === obj3.a1.b2 // true
obj1.a1.b1.c2 === obj3.a1.b1.c2 // true
```

If you must make mutations to the objects that share structural references then it would be best to past the object through something like `R.clone` just prior to mutating to ensure the other objects aren't affected. Otherwise just try sticking with functions like those in Ramda that operate in an immutable manner.

Comment: Thanks very much Scott!